# Injecting secret api key

Tags: javascript, api, api-key

how does one inject an api key into an application?

I have a secret key that I need to use, say AWS credentials

they are stored in a local file that I don't push to github

how would I inject them into the app when it loads in production so that it uses the right key?

Comment: *It depends.* There are many ways to do it, and which one's best depends on your situation.

Comment: You will have to set it as ENV vars on build time and depending on how you're setting up your application, there will be various ways of getting these variables.

Comment: what more info do you need to find a solution relevant for me?

Comment: If it's an AWS secret, take a look at this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-secrets-manager-store-distribute-and-rotate-credentials-securely/

Comment: @donut What CI are you using and where are you hosting the app?

Answer (score 0):

Use environment variables, there are a variety of ways you can set them. Such as directly in terminal or in a `.env` file that gets loaded with a [library](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv). Or your deployment solution might have a way to set them.

Then when you need them in your code use

`process.env.VAR_NAME`